# How do I get Swagger UI to provide a text box for POST body content?

Tags: swagger-ui, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

Our ASP.NET Core app has an endpoint which reads the `Request.Body` stream directly rather than using endpoint parameters and `[FromBody]`.

```cs
[HttpPost("event")]
public Task PostEvent(string clientId)
{
    _someService.HandleEvent(clientId, Request.Body);
}
```

This works great, but the Swagger UI doesn't provide a text box for the body content because it's not in the method signature.

[image: 1]

Is there a way to easily get Swagger to provide a `<textarea>` element for the body content?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently trying this in Azure Functions and found this attribute for me: [RequestBodyType(typeof(TestModel), "testmodel")]

link [here](https://github.com/vitalybibikov/AzureExtensions.Swashbuckle/blob/master/src/AzureFunctions.Extensions.Swashbuckle/TestFunction/TestController.cs)

Hopefully this will give you some hint to find something similar